# Drive side window won't move in a 1999 Saturn SC2

Tags: power-windows, saturn

The driver side window, which is electric powered, had given me some problems by not moving occasionally, then I rolled it down and remembered that it might now roll back up and as I was trying to move it up it gave out on me and is now stuck halfway up. It rolled down the other day randomly but it rarely moves at all. The passenger side window works fine, and just as a note when I say "rolled up or down" I don't mean manually "rolling" the window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely cause is a bad motor. Give the bottom of the door panel a good whack. Careful if it's cold as you can crack the door panel. This may be enough to jar the brushes in the motor to make it work long enough to get the window up.

Another way to tell if it's the window motor is with the dome light on, watch the light when you push the up or down button on the drivers window. If the light dims when you push the switch it's the window motor.

Ultimately you can take the door panel off, actually may be the door skin that comes off on that model to gain access to the motor itself. Check for power and ground by back probing at the motor while operating the switch.

Comment: Could we eliminate the possibility of it being the fuse since my passenger side window works?

Comment: @ShaneBird most likely a circuit breaker. But you said it works sometimes, so unless you changed a fuse, the fuse can't fix itself

Comment: @ShaneBird Both windows are protected by the one circuit breaker

Comment: So essentially, if the circuit breaker was the problem both of my windows wouldn't be working, right?

Comment: Basically what I'm asking is, might I be able to fix this by replacing the "fuse" or "circuit breaker", I don't know the difference between the two. Or would it be safe to say that that wouldn't work because my passenger side window still works?

Comment: @ShaneBird If the circuit breaker was the problem neither window would work. The only real options is the motor the switch or the wiring. If you will try the things I told you above you will be able to tell. The motor is the most common failure.

Comment: Ok thank you, I tried to operate the window and I didn't notice any dimming of the dome lights, hitting the panel also didn't work. I don't know exactly what your last sentence in the answer means, what is back probing?

Answer (score 0):

I just spent quite awhile fixing this exact same problem on my 2002 SC2. I tore down my driver door several times and went through everything but it turned out to be the window switch on the center console. The tiny metal contacts inside had gotten dirty and were very worn and would only sometimes make an electrical connection. Unfortunately this is an electronic part and not a simple electrical part so it's more expensive to replace. Be very careful if you take the switch apart to clean it as the small spring-loaded pieces can go flying and each switch has a thin plastic piece that's easy to break.